# What line of code do I need to add to this code in order for it to execute each function?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def f1(x,y):
    return x+y

def f2(x,y):
    return x-y

def f3(x,y):
    return x//y

def f4(x,y):
    return x*y

def f5(x,y):
    return x**y

def f6(x,y):
    return x%y

def f7(x,y):
    return y-x

def f8(x,y):
    return y//x

def f9(x,y):
    return y%x

def f10(x,y):
    return y**x

funcs=[f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10]
for i in funcs:
    print(i)
num=eval(input('Enter a number: '))
funcs[i]((3,5))
```

I know that the issue is with the declaration of `i` since i get this error message when I run the code:

```
<function f1 at 0x7f700458de18>
<function f2 at 0x7f7002ee7620>
<function f3 at 0x7f7002ee78c8>
<function f4 at 0x7f7002ee7950>
<function f5 at 0x7f7002ee79d8>
<function f6 at 0x7f7002ee7a60>
<function f7 at 0x7f7002ee7ae8>
<function f8 at 0x7f7002ee7b70>
<function f9 at 0x7f7002ee7bf8>
<function f10 at 0x7f7002ee7c80>
Enter a number: 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./lists_of_functions2.py", line 37, in <module>
    funcs[i]((3,5))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not function
```

What exactly do I need to add to get it to execute?

Comment: whats your expected output?

Comment: You should iterate over the list with an index starting from `0` up to `len(list)`. But right now your code is iterating over the list with referencing the function itself not its index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not very clear what you are trying to do. But if you are looking for a way to execute each function you just need to call them.

```
for func in funcs:
    print(func())
```

you are getting error for `funcs[i]((3,5))` because your `i` is not declared in that scope. if you want to execute all the function for a given input i.e (3,5)
do

```
funcs=[f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7,f8,f9,f10]
for func in funcs:
    print(func(3,5))
```

if you are trying to execute a specific function withing the `funcs` list, you have to provide a valid index

```
num=eval(input('Enter a number: '))
# if you want to execute num'th functions from the list
print(funcs[num](3,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

`i` is already a function. You are using `for` loop to iterate over `funcs`. instead of `funcs[i]((3,5))` change it to `i` directly `i(3,5)`